# Controls in a telerik control not accessible from .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik controls in my c# asp.net project. I am trying to disable a div in a telerik navigation menu from the .cs file. For example:

```
        if (Emp_Role == "1" || Emp_Role == "5")
        {
            DivLeave.Visible = true;
        }
```

I try run the project I get this error:

CS0103: The name 'DivLeave' does not exist in the current context

Here is an example of the aspx code

```
<telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu1" Skin="Sitefinity"   OnClientItemOpened="itemOpened"
            Width="670px" Height="26px" EnableShadows="true">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Expenses" PostBack="false">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem CssClass="Stores" Width="640px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div id="DivLeave" class="Wrapper">
                                    <h3>
                                        Expense Management</h3>
                                    </div>
```

Can anyone help with this? If I place the div outside the telerik control it works fine. This is so frustrating!

Kind regards,

R

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use a asp.net control ( or at least a control that runs in server ) to be able to access it from code behind. For example.

```
<asp:Label ID="DivLeave" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Second, to get a control inside a Telerik control you need som special code. In your example, you can do something like this:

```
 // Find menuitem by css class
 RadMenuItem expenses = RadMenu1.FindItem(i => i.CssClass == "Stores");
 // Find control inside menuitem
 Label label = expenses.FindControl("DivLeave") as Label;
 label.Visible = true;
```

To learn more:
[Accessing Controls Inside Templates](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/menu_templatesaccessingcontrols.html)

Comment: @RupDog, please place comments under the answer as im not able to comment on your "new answer". Your code dont work becasue DivLeave don't have have a item with text = "Expenses" as its parent. Thats the reason i use the css class to find the correct element in my exampel. If you want to use FindItemByText, you have to assign a text to this line:   <telerik:RadMenuItem CssClass="Stores" Width="640px">

Answer (score 0):

Doing it client side will also work and you won't have to make the div become server side.
Using jQuery you can have:

```
if (Emp_Role == "1" || Emp_Role == "5")
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "show_divleave", "$(function() {   $(\"div[id$='DivLeave']\").each(function(index) { $(this).css(\"display\", \"\"); }); });", true);
}
```

This assumes those div elements are initially hidden using *"display: none;"* CSS rule.